# Java else if statement within selenium webdriver- negative test

Tags: java, selenium, if-statement, selenium-webdriver, try-catch

So I'm testing adding an item to a cart, but realistically I want to pick the 1st Item if present and else if select the second but there's no list on https://www.prana.com/men/tops/shirts.html for the items. So I went the css selector for each of the images. To also still have the ability to have multiple items I wanted to use if- else if statements to decide between the Items. I have:

```
if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Weathered Blu22e']")).isDisplayed())
{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Weathered Blue']")).click();
}
else if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Equinox Blue']")).isDisplayed ) 
{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Weathered Blue']")).click();
}
```

the first line that has "Blu22e" is not a correct CSS title but Blue is... when I have "blue" it selects the item correctly but When I put in Blu22e ( to do a negative test and go to the else if statement I see this error:

`no such element: unable to locate such an element.`

Any ideas how I can negative test the first line? I want it to skip that and move on to the next statement
Sorry for lack of knowledge I am an intern and going to school still so my Java isn't up to par.

Comment: Why would you validate `cssSelector("a[title='Weathered Blu22e']")` with `isDisplayed()` but invoke `click()` on `cssSelector("a[title='Weathered Blue']")` ? Is that a typo?

Comment: @DebanjanB Might be a typo I don't want to validate weathere Blu22e. I want the test to check is weathered Blu22e there? ( no since its a fake name) so move onto the Else if statement

Comment: My answer is based on the same logic. Can you try it out and let me know the status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your usecase you want to click on the element `cssSelector("a[title=''Weathered Blu22e'']")` and incase it is not available within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) you want to click on the element `cssSelector("a[title='Weathered Blue']")`

In this case, you need to wrap up the logic in a `try-catch{}` block as follows:

```
try {
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Weathered Blu22e']")).click();
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Weathered Blue']")).click();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my wording may have been wrong I'm trying to bypass Weathered Blu22e and select Equinox blue. I want it to fail the first if statement and move to the next Else if statement.

Comment: @Thatbrazilian The answer is based on the same logic to look out for `Weathered Blu22e` which is _fake_ and in that case you will see a **NoSuchElementException** which will be handled by the `catch()` block only to `click()` on the **Weathered Blue** which is your else.

Comment: Thank you very Much!! this worked! 
my follow up would be could I keep adding catches for every product down the row?

Comment: @Thatbrazilian Whenever there arises a case of decision making e.g. a) either do this  b) or do that, induce `try-catch{}` to handle the exception else you won't be able to proceed  because of the _exception_. Let me know if this answers your query.

Comment: it does! thank you soo much, If I could upvote everything I would now.. but Im too new and it wont let me.. You are a lifesaver!

Comment: If I wanted to do it with just the list of items on the page- could I do something like this ? 

// This sets Child = to the first child in the list and then click the anchor point  
      WebElement Child =  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul > li:nth-child(1) a"));
      //move the mouse to Child ( the first image)
      action.moveToElement(Child).perform();
      // then click on the first Image
      action.click(Child); 

it passes but never clicks on the image

Comment: Of-coarse you can do that but the logic seems to be getting a bit complicated. Still if you want to give it a try feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement. StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in javadocs for WebDriver you will see: findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use findElements(By) assert zero length response instead. So it could be as like:

```
if (driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[title='Weathered Blu22e']")).size() > 0)
{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Weathered Blue']")).click();
}
else if (driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[title='Equinox Blue']")).size() > 0) 
{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Weathered Blue']")).click();
}
```

Comment: When I try this it says the method size is undefined for the web element. Do I need to set an element to the Css?

Comment: I tested it and it works good. In my opinion you are going to call method size() to WebElement insted of List<WebElemen>:
your variant is driver.findElement(By...).size() instead driver.findElements(By...).size()